# Automotive parts organization (taxonomy) with Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy

About to build an auto parts store and realizing that I have a bit of a taxonomy nightmare. Obviously, I have a HUGE amount of automotive categories/sub-categories BUT not sure the best way to implement the **year/make/model/trim** data. I was thinking I should use a custom hierarchical taxonomy for these as I will also be storing the user’s car(s) based on these 4 fields. Also, I was thinking of using tags for identifying other item traits such as truck/car, economy/performance, etc.

Due to the size and complexity of this project, I’m looking for experienced feedback on the best approach prior to jumping in. Thank you in advance for any help…

**NOTE: Not looking for plugin recommendations as I will be custom building this.**